# Working with date and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

1. I have a UTC date of `Tue, 16 Feb 2010 03:12:02 UTC +00:00`, for example.
2. I want to add 168 hours to this date to get a future UTC date.
3. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You tagged the question `rails` so here is how you can do this in Rails, using some of the helpers:

```
time_string = 'Tue, 16 Feb 2010 03:12:02 UTC +00:00'
new_time = Time.parse( time_string ) + 168.hours
```

If you already have it as a Time object, just add the `168.hours`:

```
new_time = old_time + 168.hours
```

Or you can just add `1.week`:

```
new_time = old_time + 1.week
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, '9.days' is more simpler than '168.hours'.

```
>> new_time = Time.parse( time_string ) + 168.hours
=> Tue Feb 23 03:12:02 UTC 2010
>> new_time = Time.parse( time_string ) + 9.days
=> Thu Feb 25 03:12:02 UTC 2010
```

Comment: OK, I have to laugh. `9.days` might be simpler, but that would make `216` hours. I think you mean `7.days` or `1.week` :)

Comment: unless of course it's the special 9 day per week calendar, where there's 18 and two thirds hours per day :)

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla Ruby it's not much more difficult:

```
time_string = 'Tue, 16 Feb 2010 03:12:02 UTC +00:00'
new_time = DateTime.parse( time_string ) + 7
```

(You could just use the Date class, it would still work.)

I admit adding in hours is a little more tricky.